# Ways to deploy an exe file over LAN

Tags: silent-install

I am trying to install Microsoft essentials security "For example" on all PCs on my network 
and as any other .exe I need to do several things like check checkbox click next button, ... question may that installation need , ...etc

I searched and see suggestion about `psexec` but there is no way to do silent installation  now what I need to know is what are best ways to do install it ?

btw if there is any System management software you advise me I ( free app if possible )

Comment: Why are you still on XP?  Is MSE even supported there?

Comment: they are still working on oracle forms 6i.. and yes i have offline exe installer and I updated from MSE update site

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have an executable doesn't mean you can install it anywhere.  According to Microsoft's documentation, MSE is not supported prior to Vista SP1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18869/windows-7-security-essentials-product-information

## Minimum system requirements for running Microsoft Security Essentials

Microsoft Security Essentials is free* and easy to download and use. Here's what you need to run it:

- Operating System: Windows Vista (Service Pack 1 or Service Pack 2), Windows 7

Comment: ok we are looking on several option and MSE was an example we are looking for kaspersky internet security or norton now what ever the exe is what I want to know is how to to do silent installation ?

Comment: Have you checked Kasperksy and Norton websites for instructions how to install their software silently?